# SQL Difference between two delete queries

Tags: sql, where-clause, sql-delete

I'm not understanding the differences between these two queries.

First of all, this is the schema:

```
 Movie ( mID, title, year, director )
English: There is a movie with ID number mID, a title, a release year, and a director.

Reviewer ( rID, name )
English: The reviewer with ID number rID has a certain name.

Rating ( rID, mID, stars, ratingDate )
English: The reviewer rID gave the movie mID a number of stars rating (1-5) on a certain ratingDate.
```

What is asked:

```
 Remove all ratings where the movie's year is before 1970 or after 2000, and the rating is fewer than 4 stars.
```

The two queries:

```
DELETE FROM Rating
WHERE mID in 
            (SELECT m.mID
             FROM Movie m JOIN Rating r ON m.mID = r.mID
             WHERE (year < 1970 or year > 2000) and stars < 4)

DELETE FROM Rating
WHERE mID in 
            (SELECT mID
             FROM Movie
             WHERE year < 1970 or year > 2000)
and stars < 4
```

Now, the first query it's not correct while the second query is, but I'm not understanding why.

In the first query I'm generating the `mID` from all movies whose rating is below 4 stars and their year before 1970 or after 2000. And then looking in Rating for that `mID` and deleting the row. (at least that's what I think it's doing)

In the second query, I'm deleting from the Rating table all those rows where the stars are less than 4 and the `mID` is of a movie whose year is before 1970 or after 2000.

Comment: Is this from the Stanford's Online course for Databases? Brings back memories :P

Comment: I think you'll see why if you run the two sub-queries by themselves.

Comment: Yes, it is.
I understand the difference in the result, I don't understand the logic difference.

Comment: Hint: movies can have more than one rating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM Rating
WHERE mID in 
            (SELECT m.mID
             FROM Movie m JOIN Rating r ON m.mID = r.mID
             WHERE (year < 1970 or year > 2000) and stars < 4)
```

In this query you are removing all reviews whose mID matches the mIDs of reviews with a rating of 4 or less stars which means that you are even deleting reviews with 4 or 5 star rating  for the movies released before 1970 or after 2000 who have atleast one review with a rating of less than 4 stars. The only check for delete a review is mID and not the rating.

```
DELETE FROM Rating
WHERE mID in 
            (SELECT mID
             FROM Movie
             WHERE year < 1970 or year > 2000)
and stars < 4
```

In this query you are checking both the conditions(movie's release year and rating) mentioned for deleting the review.